# Spawning more than one thread in Python causes RuntimeError

Tags: python, multithreading, runtime-error

I'm trying to add multithreading to a Python app, and thus started with some toy examples :

```
import threading

def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
     print 'In thread'
     print 'args are', arg1, arg2

thread = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=('asdf', 'jkle'))

thread.start()
thread.join()
```

This works beautifully, but as soon as I try to start a second thread, I get a RuntimeError :

```
import threading

def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
     print 'In thread'
     print 'args are', arg1, arg2

thread = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=('asdf', 'jkle'))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=('1234', '3763763é'))

thread.start()
thread2.start()

thread.join()
thread2.join()
```

As others seems to have no problem running this code, let me add that I am on Windows 7 x64 Pro with Python 2.6.3 32bits (if that matters).

Comment: Hum, i'm using IDLE, the basic editor that comes with python, to run this. It seems that if I run it directly from the command line, there is no problem at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, I think that the problem comes from IDLE itself, and not from my code. Thanks for your help anyway !

I upvoted your answers but will be accepting mine, as there is no real solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=('1234', '3763763é'))
```

Are you declaring the file as UTF-8?-----------------------------------------------------^

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the exact error you get?

Runs fine for me (after replacing the `é` character with an `e`):

```
In thread
args areIn thread
asdfargs are  jkle1234
 3763763e
```

If I leave the original script you posted and save the file as UTF-8 with BOM on Windows:

```
In thread
args areIn thread
asdfargs are  jkle1234
 3763763├⌐
```

Saving the code you posted as ASCII results in a SyntaxError:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe9' in file threadtest.py on line 8, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Environment information:

> C:\python -V
>   Python 2.6.2
>   C:\cmd
>   Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
>   (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

Comment: The problem is not the special char. The error I get is a popup saying "Runtime Error", probably from IDLE itself, and then it crashes.

Comment: And are there any details of the RuntimeError? We can't solve your problem if you hold back information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not holding any information. The only message I get is this alert window from IDLE saying 'Runtime error', and that's it. I guess the problem comes from IDLE, as the same code run directly from the command line works fine.

Comment: Perhaps your IDLE installation is screwed up? Might be worth an attempt at upgrading/reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you have the same filename or project name like "threading" or "Thread" under some directory and you have runned it once since this bootup.